# Why won't my Rigid Body objects stay within Passive object?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm sure this has been answered a thousand times but I can't find an exact relevant post...

I have a cluster of Active Rigid Bodies within one large Passive Rigid Body cube.  I know that the cluster of Objects will explode when I start the sim, due to all the overlap of course, but I want that explosion to stay within the cube and bounce all around the inside walls.

It isn't working and I have no idea why. I've turned up sub-steps, solidified the cube, flipped the normals, etc... nothing make any difference.  As soon as I start the sim the cluster of Rigid Bodies disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovfrbwbzeik6von/Rigid%20Body%20Gone%20Why.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container needs to be set to *Mesh* instead of *Convex Hull*, otherwise it will be considered as a full object. Also it's better to apply the scale and rotation of the objects, but to do this you'll need to make all the objects single objects (select them all then *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*). It should work:

[image]

Comment: That was it, thank you. I knew I was missing something (re: Mesh).

Comment: Would you mind explaining the bit about making them all single objects?  I've never actually understood the "User" function of Blender (fake user, single user, etc).

Comment: Fake User is something else than Single User. Fake User is used to make sure that a data will be saved even though it is not used in your scene. Single User: Objects can share the same mesh (for example if you link-duplicate an object with Alt D), if you have 2 objects that share the same mesh, Make Single User allows you to make the mesh of an object a separate mesh. Here you needed to do it because you can't apply the transform of an object if its mesh is shared with another object, because it would mean that the change would affect all the other objects that share the same mesh.

Comment: In the latest Blender versions you don't have to go through Object > Relations > Make Single User, you can directly apply the scale or the rotation and it will just need you to validate

Comment: Oh wow total Eureka! moment there.  The user thing makes perfect sense to me now, thank you for the explanation.